# Wrong source added (JSONTokener) Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, hive, pom.xml, org.json

Class JSONTokener is giving an error on the constructor JSONTokener(InputStream in). When I do Alt+Enter and select import class it imports from hive. I have hive and org.json and many others in my pom. I want it to select the correct version. This. I have written it in the pom but I don't understand why it doesn't import from this.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20160810</version>
</dependency>
```

If I view the source it doesn't has the required constructor it only as two with String and Reader but not InputStream.

EDIT:

These are the imports

```
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.behavior.SideEffectFree;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.CapabilityDescription;
import org.apache.nifi.annotation.documentation.Tags;
import org.apache.nifi.components.PropertyDescriptor;
import org.apache.nifi.flowfile.FlowFile;
import org.apache.nifi.logging.ComponentLog;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessSession;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.ProcessorInitializationContext;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.Relationship;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.InputStreamCallback;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback;
import org.apache.nifi.processor.util.StandardValidators;
import org.everit.json.schema.Schema;
import org.everit.json.schema.ValidationException;
import org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
```

And this is the line where it gives compilation error:

```
JSONObject jsonSchema = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/identification/carrier.json")));
```

Cannot resolve constructor JSONTokener(java.io.InputStream)

Comment: After you have added the dependency to pom.xml, refresh Maven dependencies in [Maven projects tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html#toolbar) by invoking 'Synchronize' button.

Comment: Doesnt helps. What i meant when i do import class is it write org.json.JSONTokener in the import statement but when I hover over the code where it is being used it give hive. or if I goto the source.

I commented the specific hive dependency in the pom and now its taking Json from some other dependency tdunning (which isnt directly in the pom itself) in com but not org.json.

Comment: What error does it show? Show us full code with imports and the error.

Comment: i've edited the question with the code and imports.